# Data from table 2 for a month when their is no data in table 1

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I have two tables A and B.

- A table has 3 months of data (Will get added every day so as the months pass more data will be added for coming months aswell)

& B table has 12 months of data (For full year).

It is possible that Table A may miss data for a month, for e.g in my case Jan doesn't has any data for one ID but for Feb it has some data for same ID.

When I take left join I am missing data for 1 ID for Jan from table 2 since table has no data for ID 1.

When I take right join I am getting 12 months of data for table 2 so applied join condition `month(table A. date)=month(table B. date)` in this case as well I am losing data for ID 1 from table2.

My requirement is to get the data from both table1 and table2 for the months in table1 and if table has no data from certain month (e.g for Jan) then also I need data for Jan from table2.

Table 1

```
ID Date         value

1  01-Feb-2019  100
2  01-Jan-2019  101
2  01-Feb-2019  102
```

Table 2

```
ID Date         value
1  01-Jan-2019  101
1  01-Feb-2019  100
1  01-Mar-2019  100
2  01-Jan-2019  101
2  01-Jan-2019  101
2  01-Feb-2019  102
2  01-Mar-2019  100
      .
      .
      .

This continues till dec 2019
```

Here in above sample data I am not getting data for Jan from table 2.

Expected output:

```
ID  Jan  Feb  Mar
1   101  201  100  //Here Jan value from table2
2   201  204  100
```

Comment: What's your expected output? Show it in the tabular form

Comment: @KaushikNayak please check my edit

Comment: So, what if for a given id and month the `value` is different between table 1 and table 2? are they always going to be the same?

Comment: @KaushikNayak value can be any random value, just need the data though table 1 doesn't have any record for the month in table 2

Comment: Ok, for a moment, looking at your expected output,I thought you were summing the values of table1 and table2. it doesn't appear to be the case..

Answer (score 0):

Try `UNION` instead:

```
select * from table A where Date between to_date('2019-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS') and to_date('2019-01-31 23:59:59', 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS')
    union
select * from table B where Date between to_date('2019-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS') and to_date('2019-01-31 23:59:59', 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS');
```

Comment: how does union work in this case, can you please help me with few lines of description

Comment: My mistake, not UNION ALL, just UNION. The point is you select all data you need from tables B and A and unite it with UNION which removes duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, for moment I can't use union is their any other way to accomplish the same?

Comment: Why can't you use that? Are there any specific requirements?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, reason I can't use union is I am implementing in tableau where I can't see union option but background is same, so asked you if their is any other option

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are extracting the values as you have not shown the actual query that gives your expected output.

This query seems to work fine, i.e. it gives what you wanted originally.

```
select  t2.id,t2.dt,coalesce(t1.value,t2.value) as value 
from t2  LEFT JOIN t1 ON
    to_char(t1.dt,'yyyymm') = to_char(t2.dt,'yyyymm') and
    t1.id = t2.id
  ORDER BY id,dt
```

If you add a `DISTINCT`, you will get a single entry per `id,month` combination if you want to remove duplicates. You may also do `group by id` or whatever you wish to get aggregation

Note that the below is only If you want to prefer table 1's value over table 2 or else simply selecting rows from t2 would be enough

```
coalesce(t1.value,t2.value) as value
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c685e56e5ca051c2717235babf8e1191)

Comment: Thanks Kaushik, yes you are right, I haven't posted the query because I am manipulating the entire process in Tableau and where I am not getting the expected data because of the mentioned issues, so planning to tweak using SQL logic, So couln't provide the full information, Thanks for your help will implement and update you the results

Answer (score 0):

If you have these kinds of restrictions in your query tools, it might be better to create a view in the database that combines the tables and then query the view.

```
create view A_B as
```

select id, date value from table A
    union
select id, date value from table B;